# What's the definition of concept of inversion in architecture? Can you also give some example for this and explanation?

Tags: architecture

It's one of questions for my exam, and I couldn't find anything about inversion related with architecture on the internet. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without knowing the material covered in the course. However, it could be referring to Robert Hooke:

> As hangs a flexible cable so, inverted, stands a rigid arch.

Which describes a way to find the funicular form for an arch by inverting the shape of a hanging cable under the same loading. In other words, [experimental form finding](http://dataphys.org/list/gaudis-hanging-chain-models/)!